# uuidgen on MacOS generates all uppercase letters

Tags: uuid

I am using `uuidgen` on MacOS and I get output like:

```
9404CF07-BBED-41F4-A81F-1FE2F04D2C9E
FFE3EF70-B04D-4614-A9AF-9A0828AF514C
7F433185-E0C4-4664-B841-AD5795751F6E
```

any reason why all the letters are capitalized? seems like with lowercase letters they could have an extra randomness of 26 in there?

If someone can tag this with `uuidgen` that'd be great.
It's a linux utility: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uuidgen.1.html

Comment: this is hexadecimal, lowercase or uppercase makes no difference.  See "Format" in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

Comment: Internet RFC4122 requires output to be lowercased. It can make difference if you deal with various standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UUID is, at its heart, a 128-bit value. The standard representation of a UUID is as hexadecimal, split into groups at certain points by hyphens; the capitalization of any letters which appear in that value is not significant.

(Note that the only letters which can appear in a UUID are A through F. Other letters are not valid.)

Comment: It's up to what "standard" you are using. Many standards such as Internet RFC require it to be lowercased at least for output.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to create an alias:

```
alias uuidgen='uuidgen | tr -d "\n" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" | pbcopy; pbpaste'
```